# Hive query with sum analytical function

Tags: hive

I have data in the below format in a hive table.

[image]

Can someone help me to write a hive query which will give me the below result.

[image]

The Result is the sum of previous 6 months without skipping months.

Here is the query I have tried, but it gives only the running totals.

```
SELECT t.key, 
       t.tran_date, 
       Date_add(Add_months(t.tran_date, 1), 1 - Day(Add_months(t.tran_date, 1))) 
       run_date, 
       month(t.tran_date) 
       month, 
       Year(t.tran_date) 
       year, 
       Sum(t.usd_amt) 
         OVER( 
           partition BY t.acct_key, Month(t.tran_date)) 
       current_month_agg_incoming_amt, 
       Sum(t.usd_amt) 
         OVER( 
           partition BY t.acct_key, Ceil(Month(t.tran_date) / 6.0) 
           ORDER BY Month(t.tran_date))
       Result
FROM   transaction_denorm_hist_tmp1 t 
order by tran_date desc;
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks for your response, I have edited the post. Could you please help me out.